# Linked server connectivity issue when connecting from ssms 2016, but ok in ssms 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an issue connecting to a linked server or running distributed queries from within `ssms 2016`, which generates an error `NT AUTHORITY \ANONYMOUS LOGON` error, when I run the same query or perform a connection test from within `ssms 2008` the problem disappears.

This is very strange, does anyone have an explanation?

Thanks

Comment: Use brackets `[NT AUTHORITY \ANONYMOUS LOGON]` to wrap the login name

Comment: Thanks, I am connected to the SQL box via AD logon, and the linked server has been configured to pass through the current security context, as I am logged in as myself, but when I try to connect I get Logon Failed NT AUTHORITY \ANONYMOUS LOGON. This only happens from within SSMS 2016?

Comment: This error is often a 'double hop' issue - do some research on double hops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating Linked Server from SQL Server to SQL Server.

Try the name of the Linked Server as [ServerName], [PortNumber]

Ex:

```
XXXServer, 1433
```

Comment: Thanks, the linked server was already in place and was created some time ago from within SSMS 2008. I have problems when connecting to it from within 2016 which we have recently installed, but its ok from within SSMS 2008.

Comment: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

------------------------------
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=10.00.5500&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=18456&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
Server Name: ----------
Error Number: 18456
Severity: 14
State: 1
Line Number: 1

Comment: Can you do a testing with option "Be made using this security context" by creating a dummy SQLID in your target server.

Comment: Yes I have tried this and the issue still persists, CANNOT CREATE LINKED SERVER ---------- 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' using current security context

Comment: Can you try with the option I have mentioned XXXServer, 1433? Please share the result of this.

Comment: **clearly this answer does solve the problem** why tick it?